# Reading messages in bulk through a Pulsar consumer

Tags: apache-pulsar

I am using node pulsar client to consume messages from a Pulsar topic. The consumer is subscribed to the topic using a `shared` subscription mode. Currently, each call to `receive` gets a single message from the topic. Is there a way to receive messages in bulk?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you get messages one by one doesn't mean that the Pulsar client doesn't use batching and other optimization techniques in the background. [Official documentation](http://%20http://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/client-libraries-java/#configure-consumer) for the Pulsar Java consumer defines the `receiverQueueSize` parameter defining accumulation of messages. By default, the Pulsar consumer uses reasonable values for its parameters and it should perform quite well for the most of the applications. Do you experience any kind of issues or slow performance?

**Update**

Since the 2.4.1 version of Apache Pulsar it is possible to receive messages in batches using consumer. First, the consumer should be created with the [BatchReceivePolicy](http://pulsar.apache.org/api/client/2.7.0-SNAPSHOT/org/apache/pulsar/client/api/BatchReceivePolicy.html) config (change values to more appropriate for your use case):

```
Consumer<GenericRecord> consumer = pulsarClient
        .newConsumer(Schema.AUTO_CONSUME())
        .batchReceivePolicy(BatchReceivePolicy.builder()
            .maxNumMessages(5000)
            .maxNumBytes(10 * 1024 * 1024) 
            .timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build())
// .. other configuration such as topic and subscription
```

Second, use the `batchReceive` method to get a batch of messages:

```
Messages<GenericRecord> messages = consumer.batchReceive();
```

When all messages are processed, simply acknowledge all of them:

```
consumer.acknowledge(messages);
```

Comment: Do we have something similar to `batchReceive` in golang?

Comment: AFAIK, it is not implemented in the golang client